# Rhino fails when run from PHP/Apache

Tags: java, php, apache, rhino

In an effort to allow some basic customization in a PHP web app with JavaScript, I'm attempting to use the PHP-SpiderMonkey library. A few of my development boxes don't have up-to-date, functioning SpiderMonkey packages available. So, to keep development moving forward, I've written a very simple wrapper around `rhino` to do the job -- again, for development and testing purposes.

This seems to be working on one machine. And it works on **all** machines when the PHP script is run from the command line. But, when run via Apache, it produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.10)
```

Is there something I might need to do permissions-wise or `$PATH`-wise to make `rhino` execute properly in PHP from the Apache/httpd process? (On CentOS 6)

---

From the console *and* via Apache, `java --version` yields:

```
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions.

First, consider using a Java Virtual Machine implementation other than `gcj`. This could easily be a `gcj` bug that we can't really chase down without matching your environment exactly. Are you also using `gcj` on the command line or using some other Java implementation? That could be the key difference.

If that's not really an option for you, I have no evidence to support my belief, but I'd try setting the Rhino optimization level to -1, if you haven't already. When run with 0 or 1, Rhino tries some aggressive optimization techniques at the class level, and these may be confusing `gcj`.

Comment: You'll need to forgive my ignorance; but, what's the best (or easiest) alternative to `gcj` -- which was what `yum install java` presumably installed. Why might it work with the PHP CLI and not from Apache?

Comment: You can get the Oracle JVM for Linux (either rpm or .tar.gz) from [Oracle's download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Another thing I had not considered is what you mean by "in a browser." Is Java running in the browser or is the error you indicated coming from the server?

If the Java is on the server, is it possible that your Apache is using `gcj` but your command line is picking up something like OpenJDK? If you type `java -version` at the command line, do you get anything?

Comment: My research indicates that `yum` on CentOS is probably installing OpenJDK, on which Oracle's implementation is based. This is probably what your command line implementation is picking up, and that's probably why it's working. Your Apache is somehow using `gcj`, and that's probably why it does not work. All of this is consistent with my speculation in my answer, so it's my best guess for now. Start with `java -version` and we can go from there. If I'm right we'll figure out what's going on with Apache; whether we can configure it to use OpenJDK or configure Rhino with optimization -1.

Comment: The question is updated to hopefully be more clear. We're talking java/rhino on the server in both cases: One via the PHP CLI, the other via `mod_php`. I'll see whether I can find evidence of multiple version of java on the box.

Comment: Another update: `java --version` yields the same information from the CLI and via Apache. (See the updated question.)

Comment: I still can't rule out that the PHP CLI is finding another Java unless we know you don't have another. Can you have a look at the [Java on CentOS HOWTO](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS) and see what Javas you have? If you have an OpenJDK we should try to configure your tools to use that; it will be more stable generally.

Comment: You mean through the `alternatives` command it gives there? ... It only shows one: `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java`.

Comment: OK. So my suggestion is to add one of the OpenJDK derivatives indicated on that page. Then set the JAVA_HOME environment variable (I am just guessing) in whatever shell environments you're executing this stuff. My expectation is that everything at that point would just work and we wouldn't have to delve into the `gcj` world.

Comment: Well, it works from the CLI. It *doesn't* work from `mod_php` Apache. I.e., `proc_open('/usr/bin/rhino -f -' ... );` works from PHP CLI, but not from the apache process. It finds `rhino` either way and runs the script; but something about the apache environment or apache's permissions seem to be getting in the way -- how do I make apache's environment mirror a local user's in the relevant way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51304/discussion-between-svidgen-and-david-p-caldwell)